# string sorting in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.2

I have below data in database.

```
01-001-A-02
01-001-A-01
01-001-B-01
01-002-A-01
01-003-A-01
```

From above, I want sorted data as below:

```
01-001-A-01
01-001-A-02
01-001-B-01
...
```

My query as below

```
var l = _context.Locs.OrderBy(o => o.loc).Take(3);

//result of the Query
01-001-A-01
01-002-A-01
01-003-A-01
```

Here is my table structure

```
public class Location
{
      [Key]
      public int id { get; set; }
      public string loc { get; set; }
      public bool isEmpty { get; set; }
}
```

I am using `Asp.Net Core 2.2, Code-First` approach. This is not a computed coloumn.

Sorting is required from right part to left after split by '-'

What am I missing in my `LINQ` query?

Comment: Can you update your question to be more clear of what are the data structure (columns and types) as well as what are `Locs` and `loc`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by each part of string separately (splitted by `-`) using `string.Split` method:

```
  string[] strArr = { "01-001-A-02", "01-001-A-01", "01-001-B-01", "01-002-A-01", "01-003-A-01", };
  strArr = strArr
    .Select(s => new { Str = s, Splitted = s.Split('-') })
    .OrderBy(i => i.Splitted[0])
    .ThenBy(i => i.Splitted[1])
    .ThenBy(i => i.Splitted[2])
    .ThenBy(i => i.Splitted[3])
    .Select(i => i.Str).ToArray();
```

Note that this requires each element to have four parts (separated by `-`). Otherwise, it will throw `t`.

Comment: Can we extend this query to support for the elements that dont have 4 parts, In such case sorting by i.Splitted[0] is enough.

Comment: @Ramesh You'd ned to write more complicated code for that. You can't do it as simply.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly the sorting should be, but you should be aware of several layers of ordering that you can implement with [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8), as such:

```cs
string[] data = new string[] {"01-001-A-02", "01-001-A-01", "01-001-B-01", "01-002-A-01", "01-003-A-01"};

var sorted = data.OrderBy(x => x).ThenBy(x=> x.Split('-')[3]);
```

Comment: Sorting is required from right part to left after split by '-'

Comment: @Ramesh you can apply the pattern I showed in the snippet to chain a number of `ThenBy` statements to sort in whichever order you want.